# Determining part size and queue size parameters for AWS S3 upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm working with the Node.js AWS SDK for S3. I have a zip file output stream that I'd like to upload to S3 bucket. Seems simple enough reading the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property). But I noticed there are optional part size and queue size parameters, I was wondering what exactly are these? Should I use them? If so how do I determine appropriate values? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is a late response.
Multiple parts can be queued and sent in parallel, the size of this parts is the parameter `partSize`
The `queueSize` parameter is how many parts you can process.
The max memory usage is `partSize * queueSize` so i think the values you are looking depends on the memory available in your machine.